# Most appropriate tech/library for 2d/projected 3d JS vector animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

Let me lay out the facts then say where I am.. First, here's the functionality I need:

- Smooth vector animation w/JavaScript
- Lines, text and curves
- Ideally, smooth (gradient) alpha blend fading at some bounds (e.g. to fade the entire scene at the bounds as an overlay?)
- To be able to project the 2d scene into 3d space.  A close approximation of what I need would be the 'Star Wars' narrative text effect ;)

(Ideally, I'd also like to be able to run code in a container (what's that headless WebKit?) and, with the aid of a host program, grab frames, push through ffmpeg and create an mpeg recording.  But that's a bonus)

Things I've found, and why I'm not sure of each:

- Raphael - haven't managed to find anything for a 3d projection or the fade effect; also not updated recently?
- Processing.js - seems outdated, not updated in quite some time.  Examples and site seem to be dated, i.e. a dying project?
- CAKE - seems very immature as a project, can't find anything with 3d projection
- Paper.js - a strong contender actually, but not sure how to combine with an alpha fade?
- JavaScript Graphics Library - the demo on their homepage (2 polygons moving around) seems to run at 10fps.  Am I too judgemental to rule it out at that? ;)

I'd like to hope that there's something in the modern CSS 3d projection and animation that I could use, perhaps wrapped loosely by an actively-maintained library.. does such a thing exist?  Or, even better, is the new CSS/canvas stuff good enough that it's easy to do it cross-platform without using an external library?

Any advice greatly appreciated.  I realise this might *seem* like an open question, but I'd accept something like 'forget processing.js, any of the other libraries will do what you want, they all write to a canvas, add a post-processing alpha blend by overlaying another canvas.', for example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the scrolling text you could use any canvas library. In [paper.js](http://paper.js) the star wars text intro could look like this:

```
var text = new PointText({
    point: [0, view.center.y],
    content: 'A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away.... \n\
\n\
It is a period of civil war. Rebel\n\
spaceships, striking from a hidden\n\
base, have won their first victory\n\
against the evil Galactic Empire.\n',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 25,
    justification : 'center'
});

text.translate(view.center, 0);

function onFrame(event) {
    text.translate(0,-1);
}
```

And then to achieve the 3D effect you could [transform](http://www.w3.org/Talks/2012/0416-CSS-WWW2012/Demos/transforms/demo-rotate3d.html) the canvas like so:

```
#canvas {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%,
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d( 1, 0, 0, 0,
                 0, 1, 0, -0.003,
                 0, 0, 1, 0,
                 0, 0, 0, 1),
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
}
```

If your background will be black you could add a black and white circular [gradient](http://paperjs.org/reference/gradient/) above the text and set the [blend mode](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#blendmode) to `multiply` to get the effect of a round fade out. Maybe it is also possible to use an svg clipping mask as described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) but I do not know if you can have a canvas inside an svg.

I made you a little script on the [paper.js sketch website](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) that works in Chrome (it is a bit hackish beause of the css added via jquery, so reload if you make some changes).

But maybe it would be easier to use a JavaScript 3D library like [three.js](http://threejs.org/) for your project.

Comment: And it seems you can use phantom.js to make videos as described here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phantomjs/wluVGGjhL90/oGBXqh7QP44J